# Running CMD command on selected files from OpenFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, openssl, openfiledialog

I'm very new to C# as I need to make simple project for my boss.

Exactly what I want to receive is:

1. Get selected files to decrypt by user (OpenFileDialog).
2. Get selected file by user to use as a key.
3. Run CMD with function openssl *enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in **userSelectedFilesToDecrypt**.enc -out **UserSelectedFilesAlreadyDecrypted**.mp3 -pass file:./**user_selected_key_file**.bin*

That's all.

What I've already got:

- OpenFileDialog for users to use on both options (1. and 2.)

What I need:

- Code for the input / output.

Here's my current code:

```
{
    Process decrypt = new Process();
    string processExecutable = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    if (!File.Exists(processExecutable))
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("The executable file \"{0}\" does not exist.", processExecutable));
    decrypt.StartInfo.FileName = processExecutable;

    decrypt.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in FILES_IN.enc -out FILES_OUT.mp3 -pass file:./KEY_FILE.bin";
    decrypt.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    decrypt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    decrypt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    decrypt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    decrypt.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    decrypt.Start();
    decrypt.BeginOutputReadLine();
    decrypt.BeginErrorReadLine();
    decrypt.WaitForExit();
    decrypt.Close();
}
```

How should I modify it, to be able to use this on files selected by user? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (String file in ofd.FileNames)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(file);

                    getCommandlineResult(file, "path1", "path2");
                }
            }

        }

        public string getCommandlineResult(string userSelectedFilesToDecrypt, string UserSelectedFilesAlreadyDecrypted,
            string user_selected_key_file)
        {
            string macAddress = string.Empty;
            System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
            pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "openssl enc - d - aes - 256 - cbc -in " + userSelectedFilesToDecrypt + ".enc -out " +
                                           UserSelectedFilesAlreadyDecrypted + ".mp3 - pass file:./ " +
                                           user_selected_key_file + ".bin";
            pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //hide window
            pProcess.Start();
            string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return strOutput;
        }
```

You have to finetune the code yourself as I have no openssl installed, but this had to help you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could test it as I'm still having problems with this.

Comment: I'll try to write a sample app tonight after work i you don't mind waiting

Comment: No, of course. Thank you for spending your free time on helping others.

Comment: @ŁukaszLipiński I added it last night and I'm wondering if you made any progress or have a follow up question

Comment: I made new class, just for OpenSSL. I made this in different way, but thianks for advice ;)